# How can I merge this mySQL queries

Tags: mysql

What should be the best way to merge the following mySQL queries? Should it get to complex? I want to sort the results by the match_score just like in the first query. I heard there is a union option to join multiple select queries, not sure how it works but is there no way to merge the 3 queries under one select query? Thanks for your time.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    ui.User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(my.interest_id) * 2.5 AS match_score
FROM
    User_Interests ui
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Interests my ON (my.user_id = ?
        AND my.interest_id = ui.interest_id)
GROUP BY ui.user_id
ORDER BY match_score DESC
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT 
    ud.User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(my.dislike_id) * 2.5 AS match_score
FROM
    User_Dislikes ud
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Dislikes my ON (my.user_id = ?
        AND my.dislike_id = ud.dislike_id)
GROUP BY ud.user_id
ORDER BY match_score DESC
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT 
    u.*
FROM
    User u
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Status us ON u.id = User_ID1 AND us.User_ID2 = 5
WHERE
    gender = ?
        AND (us.Status != 'FRIENDS'
        OR us.status IS NULL)
        AND u.birthday >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ? YEAR - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        AND u.birthday < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ? YEAR
```

Comment: What is the outer join in the third query for? It seems to me to have no effect at all. You either find a non-friend record on user 5 for a user or not, but you select the user regardless. (I suppose that User_ID1 + User_ID2 are unique in User_Status. Otherwise the join would duplicate result records.)

Comment: As to User_Status: The entry User_ID1 = 1, User_ID2 = 5 has another meaning than User_ID1 = 5, User_ID2 = 1? Or it is guaranteed that for a record a|b (e.g. 1|5) there is always a sibling record b|a (e.g. 5|1)? Or is none of these two statements true? If the latter: Wouldn't you want to look for `u.id = User_ID2 AND us.User_ID1 = 5`, too?

Comment: You should show sample data returned by the three queries, i.e. some rows for say four users that are present in one result or two or three, and the expected result for the merged query. As there will be two scores: By which do you want to sort?

Comment: I want to add both scores together, from the first 2 queries. The solo reason they exists is so I can count them together. The 3 one is a filter query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want the scores added. Okay. You also say that query 3 is for filtering, but as an outer join doesn't filter anything naturally, the only filter is on gender and date of birth. However, it seems you are trying to filter on non-friends with user 5, too. I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
select 
  u.*, 
  i.match_score as interests_match_score,
  d.match_score as dislikes_match_score,
  coalesce(i.match_score, 0) + coalesce(d.match_score, 0) as total_match_score
from user u
left join
(
  select 
    ui.user_id,
    truncate(count(*) / 2, 1) + count(my.interest_id) * 2.5 as match_score
  from user_interests ui
  left join user_interests my on (my.user_id = ? and my.interest_id = ui.interest_id)
  group by ui.user_id
) i on i.user_id = u.id
left join
(
  select 
    ud.user_id,
    truncate(count(*) / 2, 1) + count(my.dislike_id) * 2.5 as match_score
  from user_dislikes ud
  left join user_dislikes my on (my.user_id = ? and my.dislike_id = ud.dislike_id)
  group by ud.user_id
) d on d.user_id = u.id
where id in (select user_id1 from user_status where user_id2 = 5 and status <> 'friends')
and gender = ?
and u.birthday >= date(now()) - interval ? year - interval 1 year
and u.birthday < date(now()) - interval ? year;
```

You may have to make modifications, but these should be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Union is the best way to merge multiple queries at same time.Below is the way of doing it

```
SELECT 
    User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(interest_id) * 2.5 AS match_score from {

    SELECT 
    ui.User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(my.interest_id) * 2.5 AS match_score
FROM
    User_Interests ui
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Interests my ON (my.user_id = ?
        AND my.interest_id = ui.interest_id)

        union

        SELECT 
    ud.User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(my.dislike_id) * 2.5 AS match_score
FROM
    User_Dislikes ud
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Dislikes my ON (my.user_id = ?
        AND my.dislike_id = ud.dislike_id)

        union


        SELECT 
    ud.User_ID,
    TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / 2, 1) + COUNT(my.dislike_id) * 2.5 AS match_score
FROM
    User u
        LEFT JOIN
    User_Status us ON u.id = User_ID1 AND us.User_ID2 = 5
WHERE
    gender = ?
        AND (us.Status != 'FRIENDS'
        OR us.status IS NULL)
        AND u.birthday >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ? YEAR - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        AND u.birthday < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ? YEAR

} results

GROUP BY User_ID
ORDER BY match_score DESC
```

Comment: Right now there are 3 errors I get. 1 at line 5 saying unexpected select. Another 1 on line 12 saying missing crossing curly brackets and one more on line 40 saying missing crossing curly brackets.

Comment: I have updated the code.Please check and make changes accordingly